# Add an hyperlink(mail) to a message in an AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an "about" menu button and wish to add a "contact" message with my mail.
Can i put the mail address with an hyperlink to the default mail application in the phone ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `android:autoLink` in an XML definition or `setAutoLinkMask` in code on a `TextView` in your About dialog.  I would assume but haven't tried that if the text is of the form `mailto://` it will open the email app.  It opens the browser using `http://` which I have tried.

Edit:

For a basic view that you could assign the the `AlertDialog` with `setView` you could do:

```
 TextView emailLink = new TextView(myActivity.this);
 emailLink.setAutoLinkMask(true);
 emailLink.setText("mailto://<your email address>");

 AlertDialog aboutBox = new AlertDialog(myActivity.this);
 aboutBox.setView(emailLink);
```

This is psuedo code and may need modifying for your situation.

Edit:

For a more complicated view try:

```
 LinearLayout aboutLayout = new LinearLayout(myActivity.this);
 aboutLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
 TextView aboutText = new TextView(myActivity.this);
 TextView emailLink = new TextView(myActivity.this);
 emailLink.setAutoLinkMask(true);
 emailLink.setText("mailto://<your email address>");

 // addView is best used with setting LayoutParams.
 // eg addView(view, layoutParams). The following is for simplicity.

 aboutLayout.addView(aboutText);
 aboutLayout.addView(emailLink); 

 AlertDialog aboutBox = new AlertDialog(myActivity.this);
 aboutBox.setView(aboutLayout);
```

An even better way of doing this is to define your layout in XML and manually inflate it and then add to the `AlertDialog` using `addView`.

Comment: @techiServices:But me i just want to hyperlink the "contact" message, not all the "about" AlertDialog. Like that all the About AlertDialog is hyperlinked ?no?

Comment: Not sure why you are using an `AlertDialog` for an About Screen, but what you need to do is either in code or XML create a layout that contains the bits of your About Screen.  Add a `TextView` to this layout and assign `android:autoLink` if you are using XML or `setAutoLinkMask` if you are using code.

Comment: @techiServices: So i don't have to use a menu and "about" option to show the "about" AlertDialog ?! i'm confused! please can you pass me a link to understand what you're wanting to say ?

Comment: edited my answer with some code that will hopefully explain better.

Comment: @techiServices: thank you for this code/example. However, it sets all the text on the AlertDialog as a link.

Comment: the way stop that is to define a more complicated view using a layout. i will add another edit for you.